# Removing time from pandas date range function

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I have calculated a date range using pandas range finder:

```
max_date_column = ws.max_column
last_date_entered = ws.cell(row=1, column=max_date_column).value
todays_date = datetime.date.today()
Date_difference = pd.date_range(start= last_date_entered, end=todays_date, freq='D')
print("last date entered was ")
print(last_date_entered)
print("todays date is ")
print(todays_date)
print("the days not done are")
print(Date_difference)
for date in Date_difference:
 print(date)
```

The print results it gives me is seen below in the picture.
my problem is that when I go and put this into my HTML it includes the time. I don't want the time I just want the date. how can I get rid of the time?

I enter it into my html by:

```
{% for date in Date_difference %}
<h5>{{ date }}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

When i do this it presents the following onscreen:

```
Jan. 28, 2021, midnight
Jan. 29, 2021, midnight
Jan. 30, 2021, midnight
Jan. 31, 2021, midnight
Feb. 1, 2021, midnight
Feb. 2, 2021, midnight
Feb. 3, 2021, midnight
Feb. 4, 2021, midnight
Feb. 5, 2021, midnight
```

[image]

Comment: pandas datetime always has date *and* time. You cannot have one without the other. If you only want a date *string*, you can get that from strftime.

Answer (score 0):

use the datetime.datetime.now().date() method.

print(date.date())

Comment: doing todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() gives me the same result

Comment: The OP is using pandas, not Python datetime. There are subtle differences...